# Using class variables between classes Kivy file to Python file

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to access the email variable from the `LoginWindow` class so when update_date() is called from the "confirm" button in the kv file the date can be put into my `users` table where the email is equal to the email used to loign.

I am having trouble accessing the variable in the `Information` class however, having read other similar questions on here I tried setting a class variable in my `Information` class like so: `self.email = LoginWindow.email` but this didn't work.

py file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
import mysql.connector
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatButton, MDRoundFlatIconButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database=""
         )

cur = mydb.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS meet")

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (email VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255))")

cur.close()
mydb.close()

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def login(self, email):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="")
        cur = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %s and password = %s", (email, self.password.text))
        result = cur.fetchone()
        mydb.commit()
        cur.close()
        mydb.close()
        if result:
            self.reset()
            sm.current = "information"
        else:
            invalid_login()

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""

class Information(Screen):

    def select_date(self):
        picker = MDDatePicker(callback=self.got_date)
        picker.open()

    def got_date(self, the_date):
        self.date = the_date

    def update_date(self):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="")
        cur = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
        cur.execute("UPDATE users SET date_of_visit = %s WHERE email = %s", (self.date, self.email))
        mydb.commit()

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"),
                   Information(name="information"),]
        for screen in screens:
            sm.add_widget(screen)

        sm.current = "information"
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    Information:


<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"

    email: email
    password: password

    FloatLayout:

        FloatLayout:

            MDTextField:
                write_tab: False
                hint_text: "Enter your email"
                id: email
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.75, 0.15
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "top": 0.575}

            MDTextField:
                write_tab: False
                hint_text: "Enter your password"
                password: True
                id: password
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.75, 0.15
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "top": 0.4}

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                back_color: 0.2, 0.6, 1, 1
                text: "Login"
                size_hint: 0.6, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.2}
                on_release: root.login(email.text)

            Button:
                text: "Don't have an account?"
                font_size: 20
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                underline: True
                size_hint: 0.6, 0.05
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.07}

<Information>:
    name: "information"

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "My Conversations"
                on_release: app.root.current = "login"
                icon: "chat-outline"
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "Logout"
                on_release: app.root.current = "login"
                icon: "account"

        FloatLayout:
            MDToolbar:
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                md_bg_color: 0.2, 0.6, 1, 1
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: root.ids.nav_layout.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

            Label:
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                text: "Holding text"
                underline: True
                font_size: 20
                multiline: True
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "y": 0.7}
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint: 0.75, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: "center"

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Select date"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.35, "top": 0.65}
                on_release: root.select_date()

            Label:
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                text: "Holding text"
                underline: True
                font_size: 20
                multiline: True
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "y": 0.4}
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint: 0.75, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: "center"

            Chooser:
                write_tab: False
                hint_text: "Holding text"
                choiceslist: ["a", "b", "c"]
                font_size: 25
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.75, 0.15
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "top": 0.325}

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                md_bg_color: 0, 0.6, 0, 1
                text: "Confirm"
                size_hint: 0.6, 0.075
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.125}
                on_press: root.update_date()
```

Comment: Haven't tested this, but try using `root.manager.get_screen('login').password` in your `Information` rule.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying root is not defined

Comment: You're using that in the `kv` file, right?

Comment: No I tried using it in my py file, I'm not sure where I would use it in my kv file so that I can access the ```email``` variable in my ```kv``` file

Comment: To access the `email` TextField, use `root.manager.get_screen('login').email` (in the `Information` rule of the `kv` file).  To access the `password` TextInput within the `Information` window in python file, try `self.manager.get_screen('login').password`

Comment: So something like ```<Information>: name: "information" email: root.manager.get_screen('login').email``` and then access the ```email``` in the ```py``` file by doing ```email = ObjectProperty(None)```?

Comment: Without making any other changes, you can access `email` from within any method of the `Information` class by using `self.manager.get_screen('login').email.text`. Similarly, you can access `password` with `self.manager.get_screen('login').password.text`.

Comment: Ah ok I'll try this in the py file

Comment: using ```self.manager.get_screen('login').email.text``` isn't returning anything, I've check it using ```print("email is: ", self.manager.get_screen('login').email.text)``` but the only thing that's getting returned is "email is: " when I run a method in the Information``` class. I've also tried accessing the email variable using ```LoginWindow.email``` but when I print that it returns ```<ObjectProperty name=email>```

Comment: That suggests that at the time you execute that `print` call, the `email` `TextInput` has no text in it.

Comment: Umm that's odd, maybe it's to do with me clearing the ```self.email``` variable in ```reset``` method? I'll have a go at removing this